# Duda sobre realización de update a una tabla con datos de tabla temporal

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, update

vengo con una gran duda he creado momentáneamente un procedimiento almacenado para la obtención de 2 datos específicos y estos a su vez son guardados en una tabla temporal tal como se muestra en el código que detallo a continuación, la pregunta es la siguiente estos 2 datos que arroja los podría usar para hacer un update a una tabla especifica tomando como base los datos de ingreso para obtener la información en la tabla temporal.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AnalisisIngresoCta]
@FECHAI NVARCHAR(10) , 
@FECHAF NVARCHAR(10)
AS
SET LANGUAGE SPANISH;
CREATE TABLE #ROLESMEN
(   
    EMPLCOD INT,
    OBRERO VARCHAR(100),
    SECCION VARCHAR(50),
    TOTTARPIC INT,
    TOTPAGPIC NUMERIC(18,4) 
);
    
INSERT INTO #ROLESMEN(TOTTARPIC,TOTPAGPIC)
SELECT SUM(T.HORAS+T.PRODUCCION+T.DESCUENTO) AS CTAPIC , SUM(T.HORAS+T.PRODUCCION+T.DESCUENTO) AS TOTAL
FROM( SELECT E.EMPL_COD AS COD, E.EMPL_APELL+' '+E.EMPL_NOMB AS OBRERO ,E.EMPL_RUTA AS DECI, E.EMPL_CEDU AS CEDULA,
(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(MOV_VHORA),0) FROM HIS_MOV_HORA WHERE MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND (MOV_FECHA>=@FECHAI AND MOV_FECHA<=@FECHAF)) AS HORAS,
(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(DES_DESCUENTO),0) FROM HIS_MOV_DESCUENTO WHERE DES_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND (DES_FECHA>=@FECHAI AND DES_FECHA<=@FECHAF)) AS DESCUENTO, 
(SELECT DISTINCT S.SECCION FROM TBL_SECCION S WHERE S.ID_CODIGO=E.EMPL_AREA )AS AREAS,
(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(MOV_TOTALCOSTO),0) FROM HIS_MOV_PROD WHERE MOV_CODEMPLEADO=E.EMPL_COD AND (MOV_FECHA>=@FECHAI AND MOV_FECHA<=@FECHAF)) AS PRODUCCION
FROM TBL_EMPLEADO E) AS T , TBL_EMPLEADO TBE
WHERE TBE.EMPL_NOTA = 'T' AND TBE.EMPL_COD = T.COD
GROUP BY T.COD, T.OBRERO,T.AREAS,T.DECI
ORDER BY T.OBRERO, T.AREAS


    
;WITH VISTA AS( SELECT
TOTTARPIC,TOTPAGPIC
FROM
    #ROLESMEN),
    
VISTAFINAL AS(  
SELECT CASE WHEN TOTTARPIC > 12 THEN TOTTARPIC END AS TOTTARPIC,TOTPAGPIC
FROM VISTA)

SELECT 
COUNT(TOTTARPIC) AS TOTTARPIC,
SUM(TOTPAGPIC) AS TOTPAGPIC
FROM VISTAFINAL
WHERE TOTTARPIC IS NOT NULL
```

Es recomendable hacer esto que estoy preguntando, se puede realizaro o no?, que sugerencia me darían para esto, de antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendable, es un termino que alude más bien a opiniones y en este sitio, no es algo que encaje muy bien, no obstante, tienes algunos puntos que cambiar.

El primer enfoque problemático (Concurrencia), es que no estás envolviendo el código en un nivel de aislamiento que permita tener los datos sin problemas. Imagina que el motor esta haciendo la consulta. Ya ha terminado la inserción en #rolesMen, pero todavía no ha ejecutado el With Vista.... y en otra sesión se cambian los datos de cualquier tabla que no entra por el procedimiento y que hace que varíe el cálculo. El dato que aún tiene el procedure en la tabla temporal, ya no es correcto, y es lo que vas a ingresar en VistaFinal.

Segundo enfoque: La consulta que alimenta a la tabla temporal, no parece nada optimizada. Creas una temp table con 5 columnas pero solo utilizas dos. Hay un montón de tablas derivadas que quizá tendrías que darle una nueva pensada a esa query, ya que su plan de ejecución puede que no sea el mejor posible. Como este punto no es el que te ha traído la pregunta y no tenemos la suficiente información, te lo planteo, como una inquietud, pero nada más.

Además deberías de utilizar en las uniones la sintaxis `ANSI 92`

```
) As t
      inner join tbl_empleado As tbe on tbe.empl_cod = t.cod
```

Unos pequeños cambios:

```
Alter Procedure dbo.analisisingresocta 
-- Deberías de pensar en cambiar las fechas a un tipo date/datetime2
-- Además si continúas con las fechas varchar es más eficiente que nvarchar, y los
-- valores para una fecha no pueden ser nvarchar. 
                @Fechai NVarchar(10)
              , @Fechaf NVarchar(10)
As
Begin
/* Controlar la concurrencia */
    Set Transaction Isolation Level Serializable;
    Set Language spanish;
    Create Table #rolesmen
                 (
                 tottarpic Int
               , totpagpic Numeric(18, 4)
                 );
    Insert Into #rolesmen(tottarpic
                        , totpagpic)
    Select Sum(t.horas + t.produccion + t.descuento) As ctapic
         , Sum(t.horas + t.produccion + t.descuento) As total
           From (
                  Select e.empl_cod As cod
                       , e.empl_apell + ' ' + e.empl_nomb As obrero
                       , e.empl_ruta As deci
                       , e.empl_cedu As cedula
                       , (
                           Select ISNULL(Sum(mov_vhora), 0)
                                  From his_mov_hora
                                  Where mov_codempleado = e.empl_cod And mov_fecha >= @Fechai And mov_fecha <= @Fechaf
                         ) As horas
                       , (
                           Select ISNULL(Sum(des_descuento), 0)
                                  From his_mov_descuento
                                  Where des_codempleado = e.empl_cod And des_fecha >= @Fechai And des_fecha <= @Fechaf
                         ) As descuento
                       , (
                           Select Distinct 
                                  s.seccion
                                  From tbl_seccion As s
                                  Where s.id_codigo = e.empl_area
                         ) As areas
                       , (
                           Select ISNULL(Sum(mov_totalcosto), 0)
                                  From his_mov_prod
                                  Where mov_codempleado = e.empl_cod And mov_fecha >= @Fechai And mov_fecha <= @Fechaf
                         ) As produccion
                         From tbl_empleado As e
                ) As t
                Inner Join tbl_empleado As tbe On tbe.empl_cod = t.cod -- sintaxis
           Where tbe.empl_nota = 'T'
           Group By t.cod
                  , t.obrero
                  , t.areas
                  , t.deci
           Order By t.obrero
                  , t.areas;

    -- No es necesario empezar con ; sino que la sentencia anterior termine con ;
    With vista
         As (Select Case
                        When tottarpic > 12 Then tottarpic
                    Else 0
                    End As tottarpic
                  , totpagpic
                    From #rolesmen)
    -- para que el conjunto VistaFinal
         Select Count(tottarpic) As tottarpic
              , Sum(totpagpic) As totpagpic
                From vista
                Where tottarpic Is Not Null;
End;
```

El hecho de utilizar una tabla temporal, de por si no es malo.

También es posible, que te encajase mejor utilizar una función tipo table-inline.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, en lo que respecta a las indicaciones para un mejor query , pero el caso y mi pregunta es como ingresar esa información que viene de la tabla temporal a una tabla mediante un update tomando como referencia los paramentros creado para el procedimiento almacenado , me podrías ayudar o guiar por favor.

Comment: Update tabla set columnaA = tottarpic, columnaB = totpappic From tabla inner join #rolesMen temp on tabla.empId = #rolesMen.empId. Suponiendo que el punto de union de la tabla tempral y la tabla final sean el empId.